# Cookie ASPSESSIONIDSACSARTD created without httponly flag

Tags: cookies, session-management

I'm just learning right now about different analysis tools and I came across something in a nikto scan last night on a VM server I own. It said something along the lines of:

> Cookie ASPSESSIONIDSACSARTD created without httponly flag.

At first I dismissed it because it's a vulnerable server so there's like a million other things to look at also. But the more I think about it though the more it bugs me.

What could be done with custom cookies? I have tried googling this but it's possibly the most ambiguous search terms ever. My guess is that you could inject commands into cookies.

Any metasploit modules that I could look at or sites for reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there no (OWASP) code listed?

Comment: @YorickdeWid there might have been. This is way after the fact that I thought to ask. I can run the tests again tonight and add more to this question if that helps. I was just curious if anyone knew off the top of their head. If it was something common that I hadn't heard of before.

Comment: I have never seen this output, nor can I find it anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: @YorickdeWid okay no biggie. I will take a look tonight when I get home and add on to the question. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: @YorickdeWid see updated output message. There was no OWASP Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the update, I see the problem. The HTTP only flag the browser *only* lets the server set this cookie. This prevents scrips from altering the cookie data. It is a quite commonly reported by Nikto.

For more info see the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) topic

Answer (score 4):

**After Question Edit:**

A cookie with the [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly) flag cannot be read by client-side scripts like Javascript (note that the client handling the HTTP response must support the HttpOnly flag).

A page vulnerable to XSS may steal the session information in cookies and send them to an attacker.

If the HttpOnly flag is set the Javascript cannot read the cookies even if XSS is present. This prevents things like session hijacking.

Comment: So you're saying it isn't the that you can create your own cookies thats the problem but the payload you put in them? My first thought when I saw this was CGI scripts and shell shock.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Almost all times, when you use a cookie on the server side in applications, you essentially take it as a data(string) and not as some executable code. So, the cookie content is never executed. Unless it is executed explicitly via some `eval` (leads to code execution)or in a sql query string construction(leads to Sql injections).

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be that guy but I also hate being the guy that wastes peoples time with easily googlable things. After I went back and found the actual output from NikTo I was able to easily find the OWASP documentation

["HttpOnly - OWASP"](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly)

If the HttpOnly flag (optional) is included in the HTTP response header, the cookie cannot be accessed through client side script (again if the browser supports this flag). As a result, even if a cross-site scripting (XSS) flaw exists, and a user accidentally accesses a link that exploits this flaw, the browser (primarily Internet Explorer) will not reveal the cookie to a third party.

If a browser does not support HttpOnly and a website attempts to set an HttpOnly cookie, the HttpOnly flag will be ignored by the browser, thus creating a traditional, script accessible cookie. As a result, the cookie (typically your session cookie) becomes vulnerable to theft of modification by malicious script

Comment: Yes indeed, I was too late. Good you found it anyway.

Comment: @Sravan no problem, point is you found it :)

Comment: I think convention is to delete stupid questions however, I wont be the last person to ask this one so might as well document it and take my lumps haha